# How can I retrieve the features a given coordinate point sits in?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm rendering a set of MultiPolygon features from a GeoJSON file uploaded to Mapbox Studio to my custom map style.

I would like to know if the user is currently located within one of those features and retrieve its id and properties.

I found `queryRenderedFeatures` but this doesn't work, it returns `success([])` with no results. I suspect it expects canvas/screen coordinates but I need to use geo coordinates.

This is how I'm calling it:

```swift
let features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
  with: [CGPoint(x: 46.231944, y: 10.826111)],
  options: RenderedQueryOptions(layerIds: ["micro-regions"], filter: nil),
  // this print returns `success([])`
  completion: { matches in print(matches) }
)      

// features is `MBXCancelableProxy`
```

This is how I setup the style:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have geographic coordinates and need to convert them to screen coordinates, you should be able to use `points()` in the MapboxMap class.

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/10.16.2/Classes/MapboxMap.html#/s:10MapboxMaps0A3MapC6points3forSaySo7CGPointVGSaySo22CLLocationCoordinate2DVG_tF

See if this helps your `queryRenderedFeatures` call return the correct features.

Another option is the Tilequery API, which you can pass a geographic point to.  It will return features that are near that point for any tileset, and include a distance value in the response.  If the distance to a polygon is 0, it means the point lies within the polygon.

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/tilequery/

Comment: Thanks, the tilequery seems exactly what I was looking for!